# Update redmine 1.1.0 to redmine 2.2.1

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Currently i am using redmine 1.1 and now i need to update it to redmine 2.2. I have already added lot of projects and its issues in redmine 1.1 version. I have installed the redmine 2.2 in other port and use the redmine 1.1 database with the necessary changes that we need in the redmine 2.2 for maintain all my projects, issues, users in the database. But when i connect to redmine 2.2 and try to login it shows an internal error. Do anybody know how can i update redmine 1.1 to redmine 2.2 with the data that exists in the 1.1 redmine database? Please let me know whether its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, except for plugins, you should not have problems to migrate.

Backup your DB, then do a

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

Have a look at the [official procedure](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade). It's worth reading...

The main problem when migrating is usually the plugins which are not compatible.